# sed to delete line (path) from file

Tags: regex, linux, sed, automation

I am trying to delete a line from file, line is actually a path.

```
echo "/user/eventprocessor/prod/20150827" > /home/s3.success

cat /home/s3.success
/user/eventprocessor/prod/20150827

my_line=/user/eventprocessor/prod/20150827
```

Now I am trying to delete the line passed into my_line var, but doesnt work

```
sec -i '/$my_line/d' /home/s3.success
```

This does work

```
sed -i '/\/user\/eventprocessor\/prod\/20150827/d' /home/s3.success
```

Any help here please ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two issues:

1. Shell won't expand `$my_line` in single quotes
2. Due to presence of `/` in your variable `/$var/` will give error.

You can use:

```
my_line='/user/eventprocessor/prod/20150827'
sed -i "\~$my_line~d" /home/s3.success
```

Here `~` is used as an alternate reges delimiter.

Comment: I tried this sed -i '' "\~$my_line~d" /home/s3.success
sed: can't read \~/user/eventprocessor/prod/20150827~d: No such file or directory

Comment: Try `sed -i.bak "\~$my_line~d" /home/s3.success`

Comment: Plus one for a simpler solution than mine. I wasn't aware that you could specify an alternate delimiting character when matching lines with a regex.

Answer (score 0):

I would modify the `my_line` shell variable to add backslashes in front of the
forward slashes (using `sed`).

```
my_line=$(echo $my_line | sed 's!/!\\/!g')
```

The contents of the `my_line` variable is now `\/user\/eventprocessor\/prod\/20150827` and can be used in your sed command:

```
sed -i "!$my_line!d" /home/s3.success
```

Note that double quotes are used so that the shell uses the contents of the `my_line` shell variable. Single quotes prevent the parameter expansion.